# submenu still shows up when hovering his position

Tags: jquery, css, animation, menu, transition

I have a menu with subs that shows up when hovered with Jquery mouseenter and mouseleave events.

Everything works good but there's like a 2s delay after the mouseleave event that the sub still showing up when hovering just under the `li` ( the hidden sub position ). And the delay resets for each sub mouseenter/leave... I have to wait +,- 2s for the sub hide/show event to not be triggered.

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/z9t9k3te/

For my job I have 2 superposed menu and I don't want the lower one to be hidden by the upper one.
I wonder what causes that, the animation is incomplete so it "resets" the event ? And what is the best solution for the same kind of effects ?

Thanks !

Comment: I don't see any waiting time though. What is the 2s waiting time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fade out appears to be coming from the transitions here in your css:

```
transition: all 0.5s;
-webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
-moz-transition: all 0.5s;
-o-transition: all 0.5s;
-ms-transition: all 0.5s;
```

Removing these did the trick for me on your fiddle. Also, you should practice putting the w3c spec at the end of css w/ prefixes.

On a related note, is there a reason you're using opacity and visibility here? It seems much simpler to use `.hover()` and `display:none` instead of visibility and opacity:

```
$(".menu > li").hover(function(){ 
    $(this).children(".sub-menu").fadeToggle('fast'); 
});
```

Another good practice is to not hide content with CSS that you manipulate with javascript (regardless if you use `visibility:hidden` or `display:none`). If you show it with javascript, hide it with javascript.

Comment: Yes the transition seems to be the cause but transition doesn't work on display: none. I want a fadein / fadeout effect on sub. fadeToggle totally worked for me Thanks :D !

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if that is what you want, but I added

```
finish()
```

.

```
$(".menu > li").mouseleave(function(){
  $(this).children(".sub-menu").css({
    visibility: "hidden",
    opacity: 0,
  }).finish();
});
```

## JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/z9t9k3te/1/

The fading out really was astonishing.